# Myopia advancing into Presbyopia and the Optics needed to correct them

Tags: optometry

This is a question about the optics needed to correct a hypothetical situation that everyone with Myopia will eventually encounter as they advance into older age.

Given that a person has Myopia and requires -2.00 diopters of vision correction, when that person advances to the age when Presbyopia is expected, and one would be unable to focus "Up Close", then when the person with -2.00 Myopia takes off their glasses to read something "Up Close", would their vision be comparable to another person, about the same age, with 20/20 distance vision, putting on a pair of +2.00 readers or "magnifying glasses"?

In other words, would the person with -2.00 myopia have a built in advantage to be able to read things up close, as if their eyes had a "built-in" focus of +2.00?